# JAVA for loop: all except a specified number

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I need this for an array, but basically the idea is that a `for` loop will run, and whatever number you tell it to skip, it won't do. So `for(int x=0; x<50; x++)` if I want 1-50 except 22, how would I write that?

This would give me the ability to skip a certain number in my array.

Sorry if this is an extremely simple question, I am not too familiar with Java.

Answer (score 4):

Make use of `continue`, something like this:

```
for(int x=0; x<50; x++) {
   if(x == 22)
      continue;

   // do work
}
```

Suggested reading:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Comment: Arghh, there is literally (in a very figurative sense) nothing I hate more than the dreaded `if (cond) return else ...` construct. Ditto for the `continue` in this case. Normally I would let OP fix it but my hatred got the better of me :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo yeah i agree to the edit. But i believe for a beginner it is easy to understand the code with if/else constructs in place.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final void doSkippedIteration(final int[] pArray, final int pSkipIndex) {

    for(int i = 0; i < pSkipindex; i++) {
        // Do something.
    }

    for(int i = pSkipIndex + 1; i < pArray.length; i++) {
        // Do something.
    }

}
```

You would have to do some basic check to see whether `pIndex` lies within the confines of the array. This saves you from having to perform a check for every single iteration, but does require you to duplicate your code in this specific example. You could of course avoid this by wrapping the code in a wider control block which handles the two iterations in a cleaner manner.